# Magento variable to display payment method in email subject

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to display the payment method in the email subject for new order emails in Magento. The reason being is so that our client can easily determine from the subject of emails send from Magento whether the order came via the payment gateway or Paypal Express.

I'm not entirely sure of the best way to achieve this, I would like to think there is already something available I could use for this.

```
{{var payment_html}}
```

returns the payment method block for email templates...

```
{{var paymentMethod}}
```

returns absolutely nothing in the email subject so unsure whether this is a depreciated variable now.

I suppose there is also the option of creating a custom attribute, calling it in a static block and then displaying this as a custom variable in the email templates but it seems a rather long winded approach just to purely get a text string of "via SagePay" or "via Paypal Express".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You actually don't need to perform any customization, this variable is already available in the template though the object chain. This chain is supported by Magento template and allows usage of getters of the object.

In this case you need to retrieve order's payment object, then retrieve its method instance and retrieve method title from method instance. It is very simple construction:

```
{{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getTitle()}}
```

This should help you!

Comment: wow, cool feature, but is not it some mess in business logic?

Comment: @PavelNovitsky If you are confused by this method calls you can use much more simpler way: `{{var order.payment.method_instance.title}}`. It will do the same. But it is not a mess, since this is special feature added to email templates engine, so it is not required for developer to specify all the possible variables, you can just specify one object that has all the required data.

Comment: So, 'billing' => $this->getBillingAddress() is useless too with your approach :)

Comment: @PavelNovitsky Yeap, even in core email template this variable is not used, see this for instance: `{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}`. It is just a historical backward compatible variable :)

Comment: Perfect Ivan. This is exactly what I was after - thanks a million! :)

Comment: Thanks for this. You could also use order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getCode() to get the payment code like checkmo. Then it won't break if the title changes in a if/else scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail() is responsible for sending new ordr emails.

```
$paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
    ->setIsSecureMode(true);
$paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
$paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
```

...

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'order'        => $this,
    'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
)
```

payment_html is rendered html output of the block, so you can not use it.

You can add one more assoc key (using rewite or local/mage trick) with the payment method and add this param to the subject using transactional emails.

Comment: I want to attach hyperlink into payment instruction to show it on email . Do you know any way to do it?